# Показать все картинки из папки images на php

Tags: php

Нужно показать все фото из папки `images` желательно с возможностью выбора формата ( `jpg`, `png`, `gif` ).
  Нашел одну функцию в интернете, но она не очень хорошая и не знаю как добавить формат картинки `png`.

```
function search_img($path){
   $html='';
foreach (glob($path."*.jpg") as $filename)
{
 $html .= '<img class="pimg" src="'.$filename.'" alt="" />';
}
 return $html; 
}

//Пример использования:
echo search_img("images/");
```

Comment: спс , первый код работает на ура

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот еще один скрипт написанный на php для вывода фото из папки. Етот скипт нужно вставлять в блок где хочешь выводить фото.

```
<?php
    $directory = "./images";    // Папка с изображениями
    $allowed_types=array("jpg", "png", "gif");  //разрешеные типы изображений
    $file_parts = array();
      $ext="";
      $title="";
      $i=0;
    //пробуем открыть папку
      $dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("Ошибка при открытии папки !!!");
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))    //поиск по файлам
      {
      if($file=="." || $file == "..") continue;  //пропустить ссылки на другие папки
      $file_parts = explode(".",$file);          //разделить имя файла и поместить его в массив
      $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));   //последний элеменет - это расширение


      if(in_array($ext,$allowed_types))
      {
      echo '<div class = "blok_img" >
                <img src="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" class="pimg" title="'.$file.'" />
            </div>';
     $i++;
      }

      }
    closedir($dir_handle);  //закрыть папку
    ?>
```

Comment: А как сделать сортировку по имени файла?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (glob($path."*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename)
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте это:

```
$path       = '/path/to/images'; // путь к директории с изображениями
$extensions = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); // показывать расширения

$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$iteratorIterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

foreach ($iteratorIterator as $file) {
    if (in_array($file->getExtension(), $extensions)) {
        echo '<img src="' . $file->getPathname() . '">';
    }
}
```